# Can anybody help me out with this chain conversion?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I can understand that grignard reagent will attack the oxygen breaking the double bond of the oxygen forming a diol but that is unstable so it should form a Ketone but after that I can't really understand.[image]

Comment: It is a bit of a trick question. Write a balanced equation for the reaction between methyl magnesium chloride and benzoic acid, then refocus your attention!